# May a catholic take the nazerite vow?

Tags: gentiles, parshat-nasso, nozir, shimshon-samson

If a non-Jew takes the nazirite vow, may they be granted supernatural strength like Samson?

> Speak to the Israelites and say to them: If anyone, man or woman,
> explicitly utters a nazirite’s vow, to set himself apart for Hashem, [numbers 6:2](https://theisraelbible.com/bible/numbers/chapter-6)
>
> throughout his term as nazirite he is consecrated to Hashem. [numbers 6:8](https://theisraelbible.com/bible/numbers/chapter-6)

Comment: Andrew Richmond, your original question has been answered, below. See https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1231/170 for why I reverted your more recent edits. If you have a new question to ask, I recommend you ask it in a new question post. There's no shortage of space on the Stack Exchange servers.

Comment: @msh210 I thought that policy doesn’t apply to closed questions? Or is that only specific close reasons?

Comment: @DonielF, doesn't it? Why not?

Comment: @msh210 I seem to recall Isaac positing that it shouldn’t apply when the question is closed where fixing the problem invalidates the answer. But that may have been specifically by an unclear vote. I’m going to ping him on Bam and see if he remembers.

Comment: @DonielF, even if that's true, and it makes sense that it be so IMO, it only makes such sense where the edit actually improves the question to where it's openable, which didn't happen here.

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing in the Nazirite vow which gives one special physical strength, and a non-Jew does not become a Nazirite.

https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/287358/jewish/The-Nazir-and-the-Nazirite-Vow.htm

> Male or female Jews can become nazirites, but non-Jews cannot.

For more details, the source of this rule and the talmudic logic behind it, read [here](https://www.torahinmotion.org/discussions-and-blogs/non-jews-and-nezeeroot-nazir-61).